# Mouseover event affect buttons in ALL rows in list and not just on the specific button

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have some collection with dropdown list with regular  'remove' next to each row.
I added an mouseover event to change the 'remove' button's text from "X" to "Remove".
The problem is that the text is changing for ALL buttons and not just for a specific button.

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/z22m1798/27/

**Javascript:**

```
     var CartLine = function(siblings) {
   var self = this;

   self.availableFilters = ko.computed(function() {
        return filters.filter(function(filter) {
        return !siblings()
            .filter(function(cartLine) { return cartLine !== self })
            .some(function(cartLine) {
            var currentFilterValue = cartLine.filterValue();
            return currentFilterValue &&
              currentFilterValue.name === filter.name;
          });
      });
   });

   self.filterValue = ko.observable();
 };



 var Cart = function() {
   // Stores an array of filters
   var self = this;

    self.btnRemoveTxt = ko.observable("X"); 
   self.lines = ko.observableArray([]); 
   self.lines.push(new CartLine(self.lines))// Put one line in by default

     self.sortedLines = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.lines().sort(function(lineA, lineB) {
        if (lineA.filterValue() && lineA.filterValue().name == "Text") return -1;
      if (lineB.filterValue() && lineB.filterValue().name == "Text") return 1;
      return 0;
    });

   });

   // Operations
   self.addFilter = function() {
     self.lines.push(new CartLine(self.lines))
   };

   self.removeFilter = function(line) {
     self.lines.remove(line)
   }; 

   self.btnRemoveOver = function() {
        console.log("Yey");///////////////
        self.btnRemoveTxt("Remove");
    }
    self.btnRemoveOut = function() {
        console.log("Yey");///////////////
        self.btnRemoveTxt("X");
    }
 };

 // Some of the Knockout examples use this data
 var filters = [{ 
     "filterValues": [{"name": "", }, ], "name": "Text" }, {
   "filterValues": [{"name": "Yes",}, {"name": "No",  }, ],"name": "Choice1" }, {
   "filterValues": [{"name": "Yes",}, {"name": "No", }, ], "name": "Choice2" }];

 //Load initial data from server
 var JSONdataFromServer =  $("#JSONdataFromServer").val();
 console.log(JSONdataFromServer);
    var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='liveExample'>
<input type="hidden" id="JSONdataFromServer" value='[{ "filterValues": [{"name": "Test"}], "name": "Text" }, { "filterValues": [{"name": "Yes"}, {"name": "No"}], "name": "Choice2" }]'/> 
  <table width='100%'>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: sortedLines'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Choose option:
        </td>
        <td>
          <select data-bind='options: availableFilters, optionsText: "name", value: filterValue'> </select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="with: filterValue">
          <!-- ko if: name === "Text" -->
          <input type="text">
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko ifnot: name === "Text" -->
          <select data-bind='options: filterValues, optionsText: "name", value: "name"'> </select>          
          <!-- /ko -->

        <td>
<button class="widthFull buttonInput" href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeFilter, visible: $parent.lines().length > 1, event: { mouseover: $parent.btnRemoveOver, mouseout: $parent.btnRemoveOut }'><span data-bind="text: $parent.btnRemoveTxt"></span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button data-bind='click: addFilter'>Add Choice</button>
  <br>
  <input type="submit"Submit</>
</div>
```

Someone can assist me here?
I am new with Knockout.js.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `btnRemoveText` is a shared property (it's in `$parent`). You need to add it to each `CartLine` if you want it to work as you intended.

**However**, I'd suggest simply using css for this feature:

```
.buttonInput::after {
  content: "X";
}

.buttonInput:hover::after {
  content: "remove";
}
```

With the much simpler html:

```
<button class="widthFull buttonInput" href='#' data-bind='
  click: $parent.removeFilter, 
  visible: $parent.lines().length > 1'>
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8z3agfwc/

To be complete: If you *do* want to move the functionality to the `CartLine` viewmodel:

html:

```
<button class="widthFull buttonInput" href='#' data-bind='
  click: $parent.removeFilter, 
  visible: $parent.lines().length > 1, 
  event: { 
    mouseover: btnRemoveOver, 
    mouseout: btnRemoveOut 
  }'>

  <span data-bind="text: btnRemoveTxt"></span>

</button>
```

js:

```
var CartLine = function(siblings) {
  var self = this;

  self.btnRemoveTxt = ko.observable("X");

  self.btnRemoveOver = function() {
    self.btnRemoveTxt("Remove");
  };

  self.btnRemoveOut = function() {
    self.btnRemoveTxt("X");
  };

  // etc.
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4ys35st/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanations!! may I ask you why you prefer the CSS solution? is it because the HTML is clearer?

Comment: Good question. Might be mainly personal preference. It's just that this aesthetic functionality needs three exposed viewmodel properties and two event listeners per row to work. I'm not sure if there are any issues with accessibility and `::after` content though...

Answer (score 1):

Every entry in your sortedline array basically binds to the same property. You are using 
 $parent.btnRemoveTxt as the text. Every sortedline should have it's own btnRemovetxt property

Add a btnRemoveTxt property to the sortedline entries and bind that one to the span.

For the click event you could still use a function on the parent level but then you should pass through the actual entry and change the text on that entry alone.